# IPv4 changes by itself

Tags: ip, ip-address, ipv4

My IPv4 address randomly changes by itself but I can't figure out why ?

It changes from 192.168.0.10 to 192.168.0.13 and vice versa.
That happens doesn't happen often but very randomly...

Does anyone know why is that happening and how could I prevent that from happening?

Could VPN have something to do with that ?

Comment: Do you have a wired and a wireless NIC? Or two wired networks with different IPs for the same wireless card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What IP are you looking at?
Are you looking at the assigned IP of the network adapter? If yes, are you sure you're looking at the same network adapter?
Normally when you VPN, a new (virtual) network adapter is created and the internet connection goes through this one. It is normal for it to have a different IP address.

IP addresses in the form of 192.168.X.Y are assigned by a [DHCP server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol). As an example, your router is a DHCP server. Once an IP is assigned by the server, it has a "lease time". That means that if the device disconnects from the network for a period of time longer than the lease time, that IP address can be re-utilized within the network

It is possible that if you have a lot of devices connected to the same router, and if your computer is off for extended periods of time (usually longer than 24h) the IP that was in the past assigned to the computer will be assigned to a different device, and when the computer connects to the network again, it will get a new address.

In this case, to fix a specific address to a specific device, go to your router and look for "address pinning" somewhere around the DHCP settings.

Comment: So I should either extend lease time(which is at 60 minutes now) or I have option in my router "Pre-assigned DHCP IP Addresses" so then I assign my MAC to specific IP ?

Comment: If you explicitly want the same IP, use the "Pre-assigned DHCP IP Addresses" to map an IP to the MAC of your computer. The MAC never changes, unless you change the network card.

Extending the lease time helps, but it's not a guarantee that it will not change.

Comment: To be honest, 60 min seems a bit low. I would increase that to 8h at least. Unless you have way too many devices. (i am sure you don't)

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, would you kindly mark my answer as the solution? (feel free to double check that it does work, of course)
Thank you!

Comment: Oh, sure, haven't seen the tick icon...I just started using superuser :D

Comment: No worries. :) Welcome to superuser!

Answer (score 0):

Check for the leasetime in DHCP (LAN) section of your modem. Lowest the leasetime, your ip changes randomly

Comment: Many DHCP licenses are renewed when half the license time is up. That means that the IP should not change as long as you remain connected to the network. And many SOHO routers go beyind that and keep the IP/MAC combination reserved. Which means this likely is not the cause.

Comment: But, @LongLife didn't specify whether the ip changes while he is connected, so lease time can be a case.. I once had this problem with my modem (iball-baton 150M Wireless-N ADSL2+ Router)

Comment: It is possible, but unlikely. Most (actually, all devices I have used) do not doit that way.